# Typo3 9 Speaking URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, typo3, url-routing, typo3-9.x

In the [Typo3 v9 Roadmap](https://typo3.org/article/typo3-v9-roadmap/) it was written that with version 9.3 URL Routing will be implemented. I can not find any way in this version to accomplish nice looking URLs.

Extensions like RealUrl or CoolUri are not working either.

Is there any elegant workaround for getting speaking URLs in Typo3 9.3?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, the `9.3` includes only "URL Routing Preparations". The final URL Routing shall be included in `9.4`, estimated 04.09.2018.

[TYPO3 Roadmap Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Ejb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the [Roadmap](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/roadmap) the implementation is still not done, it's planned for the next two month. 
You can have a look at the single items, some of them are helicopter- or umbrella-items which means they might consist of several sub-items and are primary there to collect issues to solve.
Here the related main-items copied from the roadmap:

> Epic [#83796](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/83796): Site Handling
>   Epic [#84727](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84727): Site Handling - Part 2 / Missing Pieces
>   Epic [#84728](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84728): Introduce speaking URLs for pages and other records
>   Epic [#84729](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84729): Implement "slug" handling for pages and other records
>   Epic [#84730](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84730): Configuration of resolving and building slugs

About the timeline the planned two months might be already over as the "two months" seem having been set in April, nevertheless it seems there wasn't enough success yet.

Comment: Thank you for the breakdown.
Really helpful would be a workaround in the meantime :)